# Broadcast receiver only works when app is opened

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I created a auto sms application which sends SMS automatically when a firebase notification is received. I am able to send SMS extending `FirebaseMessagingService`. Now to get the sent status i created a broadcast reciever inside my main activity. 
Here i am able to get the SMS send status only when App is in opened. I need to get that even if app is background.

My reciever is :

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = null;
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    message = "Message sent!";
                    Log.e("DATA", message);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    message = "Error. Message not sent.";
                    Log.e("DATA", message);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    message = "Error: No service.";
                    Log.e("DATA", message);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    message = "Error: Null PDU.";
                    Log.e("DATA", message);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    message = "Error: Radio off.";
                    Log.e("DATA", message);
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Register reciever in onCreate:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.SMS_SENT));
```

My firebase service sends the sms using:

```
private void sendSms(String phonenumber[],String message)
    {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(Constants.SMS_SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(Constants.SMS_DELIVERED), 0);
            int length = message.length();
            if(length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            {
                ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(message);
                for(String number : phonenumber) {
                    manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, messagelist, null, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(String number : phonenumber) {
                    manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, piSend, piDelivered);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you register in manifest class.?
if not then register your broadcast in manifest and use a separate class for broadcast
you can read more from here. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8836be/how-to-create-global-broadcast-receiver-and-test-service-in/

Answer (score 0):

If you are unregistering receiver in onPause() then it might not work. Try to move the unregister code to onStop() or onDestroy()